# How to find out what are accept, loop and reject in this Turing Machine?

Tags: terminology, turing-machines

I am trying to find out accept, loop and reject in this Turing Machine because it doesnt have any...I am not sure if I completely understand it but this is the turing machine I am talking about...

[image]

so accept state would be --> `Accept(T2) - all words with a a`
                      loop state would be --> `Loop (T2) - /\`

reject state would be --> `Reject(T2) - Strings with b`

am I on a right track ? how could I do find accept, loop and reject on this TM? thanks!

Comment: The questions and answers on this site are archived for later reference. That means that it is generally a bad idea to augment your question as you've done by adding another part to your original. In this case, for instance, you've made Yuval's answer confusing, since when he answered there was only one TM description and now there are two. It would have been better to have made your addition into a separate question.

Comment: What do you mean by "find out accept, loop, and reject"?  I'm having a hard time understanding the question. Would you like to edit the question to explain more clearly what your question is, and what reading you've done on this topic?

Comment: "Because it doesn't have any.." Because it doesn't have any what?

Answer (score 2):

Yuval's answer applies to your machine T$_2$. With his assumptions, we have the following behavior for your T$_1$ on possible inputs:

- It will reject the empty string, since there is no move defined on the "blank" symbol.
- It will not accept any string consisting only of $a$ characters, since it won't reach the HALT state.
- It will accept $a\dots ab$, since it will reach the HALT state.
- If the input is a single $b$, it will enter the HALT state and will then fall off the left end of the tape. Whether that should lead to acceptance or rejection depends on your definition of "accept" and "reject".
- Whether it will accept a string like $aba$ or $abb$ will depend on your definition of "accept", since in these cases it will enter the HALT state and will never process the characters beyond the first $b$.
- There is no loop state, at least under Yuval's and my interpretation.

You need to look closely at your local definition of a TM, since there are several forms they might take and of course we have no way of knowing what definitions you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is non-standard, but I assume that:

- The Turing machine *accepts* when it reaches the HALT state.
- The Turing machine *loops* if it never terminates.
- The Turing machine *rejects* if it gets "stuck", i.e., at some state it sees some symbol $\alpha$ but there is no outgoing arrow labelled $\alpha$.

Assuming this terminology, your answer is almost correct:

- Inputs starting with $aa$ are accepted.
- No inputs result in an endless loop.
- All other inputs are rejected.

You claimed that all inputs having $b$ are rejected (you're assuming the alphabet is $\{a,b\}$). This is correct, but there are a few other strings which are also rejected – can you see which?

Comment: since the alphabet is gonna be {a,b} could a,b or b,a or anything that has a,b also be rejected ?

Comment: actually I was thinking "Reject(T2) - Strings with 'b' and ending in 'a'...is this ok now ?

Comment: Don't guess! Since every string is either accepted, causes of loop, or is rejected, and we have a description of the first two cases, you should be able to come up with a description of the third case.  It consists of all those strings *not* starting with $aa$. Most of these contain a $b$, but not all.